# How could I edit the information on popup window in NetSuite?

Tags: oracle, popup, netsuite

How could I edit the information on popup window in NetSuite?
Like this photo, I wanna to show some other information in this popup window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKSku.png)

I want to edit the information of item colume in Purchase Order.

Is there any way to do that?
Maybe using some script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Customizaton / Forms /Entry Forms

- find the default form for the record type for which you want to adjust the quick-vew
- Edit that form.
- there is a 'Quick View' tab
- add/remove/re-order the fields needed
- save the form

Repeat as needed (non-inventory items have different forms than inventory items etc)

There are also much more complex ways to accomplish this by adding scripts to the page but that's a whole other story.

edit based on comment:
Something like the last X prices of the item could be added as custom item fields. These fields would be no different from any custom fields. They can be non-saved and derived from saved search outputs or they could be calculated daily in a map reduce script on items that have been purchased in the previous 24 hours. (or 36 for some extra effort but no missed transactions)

Comment: I find it ,thank you!
But could I add some thing on it?
Like the last 4 prices of this item .

Comment: See my edit to the answer

Comment: Could you tell me how to add the last 4 prices of item as custom item fields

Comment: Not an answer for comments and probably should be in its own question